# Android ==> Loggin witthout going to debug mode?

Tags: android, debugging, logging

Is there any way to log within the application without being in debug mode.
When i am in debug mode the application runs tooo slow.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the Lod.d/w/e methods? They work perfectly fine for me when just running the app. I also avoid debug mode because it is dog slow :/

Comment: Are you referring to the log cat in eclipse? please make your question more specific so people know how to answer your question.

Comment: Yes i am referring to the logcat.
It only logs on debug mode.
How did u get it to log without being in debug?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Log.d()? This will only show up in debug mode, but I'm pretty sure Log.i(), and w() and e() will always get logged.

Comment: weird i am using Log.i() and it's not logging.
I think im gonna use Log4j instead of logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a way to show only `Log.d()` msgs on Eclipse's logcat view.
Try running:

```
adb shell logcat
```

to see everything.